# Bootstrap Carousel not working inside pill content

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have my carousel code in `file2.php`. It is working fine. 
But when I try to load that into a tab content of `file1` (div `myhome`), the carousel just remains static. I tried adding 'display:block' in tab-content in CSS file but it didnt work

file1.php:

```
<ul id="mainpill" class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
  <li id="tab0">
    <a data-toggle="pill" href="#home">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    <div id="myhome"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

file2.php:

```
carousel code
```

file3.js:

```
$('#tab0').click(function() {
  $('#myhome').load('file2.php');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

please change your file1.php and file3.js code :

```
file1.php

    <ul id="mainpill" class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
      <li id="tab0">      
        <a href ="#" onclick="load_home()"> 
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> 
        </a>  

      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
        <div id="myhome"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

**file3.js**


 function load_home() {
     document.getElementById("myhome").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="File2.php" ></object>';
}
```